# file absolute path not working

Tags: php, wamp, filepath, absolute-path

I am trying to **include an mp4 file in a PHP file** ("video-view.php"), the code is like:

```
<video autoplay muted controls>
    <source src="<?php echo "$videoLocAddress"; ?>" type="video/<?php echo $type; ?>">
    <p> Your Browser doesn't support videos</p>
</video>
<a href="<?php echo $videoLocAddress; ?>" download>Download this video</a>
```

here `$videoLocAddress= "C:\wamp64\www\LokMedia\Data\videos\123456.mp4"`
and `$type = "mp4"`
and when I hover on the anchor tag, it gives the path:

```
file:///C:/wamp64/www/LokMedia/Data/videos/123456.mp4
```

**but does not allow me to download the file.**

my PHP file location is `"C:\wamp64\www\LokMedia\video-view.php"`

PS: **It works fine when paths are relative** i.e. `$videoLocAddress= "Data\videos\123456.mp4"` but I have to use absolute path.

Comment: thats because you are using webserver , the relative path works because the path appends localhost/youprojectname/...... and not C://........, to download file you need to have the url and not disk path

Comment: _It works fine when paths are relative_ Then use relative paths.

Comment: never use absolute paths - no one shares the same C:\ format. Also - usually, 9.9/10 you'd host on a Linux machine anyway, so this would fail straight away

Comment: I have to host it on localhost, as it is being designed for an internal server. the data is going to be on external hard drives, so absolute paths are compulsory.

Comment: @UbaidurRehman even with external drives - you don't need to use full paths, or at least I hope not.. that would be the opposite of efficient

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs can you elaborate it, please? TIA

Comment: @UbaidurRehman because if any slight file changes location, you have to change it for X amount of files - not sure why you're not allowed to keep files on the same disk?